# Routers apparently doing nothing locally in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I recently was fiddling with Backbone.js and I got everything to work (Models/Views/Events/Collections) except the Router. Here is my js/router/test.js file.

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        ''              :   'index',
        'projects/:id'  :   'show'
    },  

    start: function() {
        Backbone.history.start({ pushState : true }); 
    },  

    index: function() {
        alert('index');
    },  

    show: function(id) {
        alert(id);
    }   
});

var router = new Router();
router.start();
```

And here is my test.html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title> sup </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p> hello </p>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.5.2/underscore-min.js"> </script> <!-- underscore.js -->
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.0.0/backbone-min.js"> </script> <!-- backbone.js -->
    <script src="js/routers/test.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I put an alert('Hi!') in initialize: within my Router the alert pop ups correctly. I am navigating to `file:///Users/myname/Projects/backbone/test.html` as the base page. Should I be setting a urlRoot somewhere? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried running this through a local web server? Things behave quite differently with `file://` URLs.

Comment: This was the problem. I had to serve the files through my ~/Sites folder (OS X 10.9) and configure + start Apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Backbone.js acts differently using file:/// URLs and needs to have a webserver serving the files.

The solution was to move my files into my ~/Sites folder and configure and start Apache. I followed the guide here: http://www.coolestguidesontheplanet.com/downtown/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-osx-109-mavericks.