# How can I test Backbone Router Hashing locally?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

What I mean is as I set up a hash route per the cdnjs tutorial it is assumed testing as if the page was hosted somewhere (i.e. `mywebsite.com/#/posts/23/`) whereas I am current hosting it locally so my address looks something like `file:///C:/Folder/index.html`.

My question is how do I properly test this hash route using that method. I have tried appending the current filepath like so `file:///C:/Folder/index.html/#/posts/23` but this does nothing. Perhaps my code is the main issue; however, it is basically a copy of what is provided by cdnjs. The code works for the initial page (i.e. I get the null action alert by the default route) so I know as much as that working.

Router code:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "posts/:id": "getPost",
        "*actions": "defaultRoute"
    }
});

var app_router = new AppRouter;

app_router.on('route:getPost', function(id) {
    alert("get post number " + id);
});

app_router.on('route:defaultRoute', function(actions) {
    alert(actions);
});

Backbone.history.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a simple node server to serve the index route.

try using `serve`:

```
$ npm install -g serve
```

then you can `cd` to the proj root directory, and run with:

```
$ serve .
```

by default I *think* it serves at `http://localhost:3000` so you want to point your browser there.

**EDIT**

Short answer is, you need to serve the files with a webserver, what you use is your choice, but as you said, you will be unable to use an absolute file path.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Backbone does not function properly using the `file///` URL. See this answer: [Routers apparently doing nothing locally in Backbone.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23865516/routers-apparently-doing-nothing-locally-in-backbone-js)

The answer was to use Apache; however, this doesn't particularly help me because I am unable to use Apache webserver. Still looking for another solution but I figured I'd post this as well.